# Select rows that match several conditions

Tags: sql

I have a table `pupil_teachers` like so

```
+------+----------+------------+
| id   | pupil_id | teacher_id |
+------+----------+------------+
| 1    | 100      | 200        | 
| 2    | 101      | 200        |  
| 3    | 102      | 200        |
| 4    | 102      | 201        |
| 5    | 101      | 201        |
| 6    | 101      | 202        | 
| 7    | 103      | 200        | 
+------+----------+------------+
```

The query would be to retrieve all teachers that pupils 100, 101 and 102 have in common. So in this case it would only be teacher with id 200.

Pupil 103 also has teacher with id 200, but is not part of query, I only want to query pupils 100, 101 and 102.

So it would start with:

```
SELECT teacher_id
FROM pupil_teachers
WHERE
```

I really don't know where to go next. Obviously the following is not correct

```
SELECT teacher_id
FROM pupil_teachers
WHERE pupil_id IN (100, 101, 102)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way using `Group By` and `Having` clause

```
SELECT teacher_id
FROM pupil_teachers
WHERE pupil_id IN (100, 101, 102)
Group by teacher_id
Having Count(Distinct pupil_id) = 3
```

Another way

```
SELECT teacher_id
FROM pupil_teachers
Group by teacher_id
Having Count(Case when pupil_id  = 100 then 1 end) > 0  
   AND Count(Case when pupil_id  = 101 then 1 end) > 0 
   AND Count(Case when pupil_id  = 102 then 1 end) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Worked like a charm. I did find a similar solution like your first one, tried it, but I had to have some kind of error, as it didn't work, lol. Thanks! I'll accept as soon as I can!